# Problems installing react bacause of dependencies with babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, terminal, create-react-app

Basically this. I've tried with both

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

and

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

and I get always this message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @babel/core@7.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/core
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"7.12.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"^7.12.3" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!     @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (babel-jest, babel-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @babel/core@"^7.13.0" from @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining
npm ERR!   @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@"^7.13.12" from @babel/preset-env@7.14.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm ERR!     @babel/preset-env@"^7.12.1" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!       @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Zio Matteo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zio Matteo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-08T08_46_00_758Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting first/ from C:\Users\Zio Matteo\Desktop\react
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Zio Matteo\Desktop\react
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app "first"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Zio Matteo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-08T08_46_01_359Z-debug.log
```

I've also updated node but nothing works. My package.json is empty because this is the first package I'm trying to install, so I don't have node_modules folder neither. What can I do?

Comment: Zio, can you tell us what node.js version you have ?

Comment: did you try your command with --force ?

Comment: In generale, it is related to the npm version, what is your npm version ?

Comment: I'm using npm 7.16.0 and even with --force it doesn't work

Comment: you need to update your node version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an issue of npm version. Upgrade to the latest version of npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Also add babel:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
```

If this solution doesn't work, you can simply try older npm version:

```
npm install npm@6.14.11 -g
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working for me, it's showing the same err message

Comment: check out the node version please: npm current node -v

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just had to use the windows powershell as an administrator instead of using the terminal from visual studio and then do what you suggested